# How to use Quotation Marks in StringFormat of Binding in WPF

Tags: wpf, binding, string-formatting

I'm trying to wrap a TextBlock's Text property (which is a string that is pulled from the database) in quotes without using a converter; I'd never tried the Binding's StringFormat property before today, and I seem to be doing something wrong.

Here is the code that isn't working:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding QuoteText, StringFormat='\"{0}\"'}" />
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is XML, so `&quot;` is your friend.

Comment: Oh, Lord.. of course. Thanks, and +1 for answering within, what, two minutes? :)

Comment: Not your friend but your requirement :)